# using orchard how to tidy up a form

Tags: css, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have setup a content type to hold 3 boolean fields. Then use the content type in a form to display on screen. Only trouble is I want to tidy up the appearance of it and am not sure how to do this.

I would like the radio buttons to appear horizontally aligned and also a 2 line space after each question.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an Orchard question, more one for CSS. The simplest way to make the radio  buttons appear horizontally is to float them left.

```
input[type="radio"] {
   float: left;
}
```

And then just add some padding to the bottom of each question. I'm not sure what the mark up looks like, but I guess each question in the form has a div on which you can add the padding.

EDIT: I'm a CSS hack and Bertrand has pointed out a better way of achieving this using `display:inline-block` for the horizontal radio buttons.

Comment: Float is not for this. display:inline-block will do a better job.